# Xamarin android drawable resources folder image size?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, default, android-drawable, image-size

I am very curious what kind of size of images I have to hold in Resources -> drawable folder.
Because in other drawable folders like mdpi, hdpi and etc I am holding size of images regarding documentation. As I know in drawable folder there should be default images if device do not recognize what kind of type of drawable folder is required, then application loads from default folder - drawable. So what kind of size images, you would suggest to put? Thank you for all answers and suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I find out that is mostly recommended to have images in drawable folder(default) from drawable-hdpi folder.
And here is recommended sizes for each folder: http://iconhandbook.co.uk/reference/chart/android/